# KeyError by inserting csv to Database?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, csv

I am really up sad. Some of my CSV-Files of Stackoverflow dont get inserted into my local database. Because I get an KeyError. The problem it dont work for the Id of posts.csv instead it work for the id of tags.csv.

Here is **5 rows** of `posts.csv`

```
4,1,7,2008-07-31,21:42:52,543,34799,"b""<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>\n\n<p>This is my code:</p>\n\n<pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000

6,1,31,2008-07-31,22:08:08,241,15696,"b'<p>I have an absolutely positioned <code>div</code> containing several children, one of which is a relatively positioned <code>div</code>. When I use a <strong>percentage-based width</strong> on the child <code>div</code>, it collapses to \'0\' width on <a href=""http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7"" rel=""noreferrer"">Internet&nbsp

7,2,None,2008-07-31,22:17:57,391,None,"b""<p>An explicit cast to double like this isn't necessary:</p>\n\n<pre><code>double trans = (double) trackBar1.Value / 5000.0

9,1,1404,2008-07-31,23:40:59,1716,439828,"b""<p>Given a <code>DateTime</code> representing a person's birthday, how do I calculate their age in years?  </p>\n""",1,How do I calculate someone's age in C#?,"c#,.net,datetime,",64,376

11,1,1248,2008-07-31,23:55:37,1286,130055,"b'<p>Given a specific <code>DateTime</code> value, how do I display relative time, like:</p>\n\n<ul>\n<li>2 hours ago</li>\n<li>3 days ago</li>\n<li>a month ago</li>\n</ul>\n'",1,Calculate relative time in C#,"c#,datetime,time,datediff,relative-time-span,",34,528
```

My Code:

```
def writePostsToSql():
    con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (Id, PostTypeId, AcceptedAnswerId, Date, Time, Score, ViewCount, Body, OwnerUserId, Title, Tags, AnswerCount, FavoriteCount, PRIMARY KEY (Id), FOREIGN KEY (AcceptedAnswerId), FOREIGN KEY (OwnerUserId));")  # use your column names here

    with open('Posts.csv', 'r') as fin:  

        dr = csv.DictReader(fin)  # comma is default delimiter
        to_db = [(i['Id'], i['PostTypeId'], i['AcceptedAnswerId'], i['Date'], i['Time'], i['Score'], i['ViewCount'], i['Body'], i['OwnerUserId'], i['Title'], i['Tags'], i['AnswerCount'], i['FavoriteCount']) for i in dr]

    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO posts (Id, PostTypeId, AcceptedAnswerId, Date, Time, Score, ViewCount, Body, OwnerUserId, Title, Tags, AnswerCount, FavoriteCount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", to_db)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

My Gues would be that it can not read the id because of the inserted blank space between my DataSets. How can I change my code that he should ignore the Blank spaces.

I hope you guys can help me and if there is an Question then please ask.

Best Regards

Tobias

Answer (score 0):

In your file post.csv you haven't include headers (titles of the columns). So if you have the post.csv file with the following content:

```
Id,PostTypeId,AcceptedAnswerId,Date,Time,Score,ViewCount,Body,OwnerUserId,Title,Tags,AnswerCount,FavoriteCount
4,1,7,2008-07-31,21:42:52,543,34799,"b""<p>I want to use a track-bar to change a form's opacity.</p>\n\n<p>This is my code:</p>\n\n<pre><code>decimal trans = trackBar1.Value / 5000

6,1,31,2008-07-31,22:08:08,241,15696,"b'<p>I have an absolutely positioned <code>div</code> containing several children, one of which is a relatively positioned <code>div</code>. When I use a <strong>percentage-based width</strong> on the child <code>div</code>, it collapses to \'0\' width on <a href=""http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7"" rel=""noreferrer"">Internet&nbsp

7,2,None,2008-07-31,22:17:57,391,None,"b""<p>An explicit cast to double like this isn't necessary:</p>\n\n<pre><code>double trans = (double) trackBar1.Value / 5000.0

9,1,1404,2008-07-31,23:40:59,1716,439828,"b""<p>Given a <code>DateTime</code> representing a person's birthday, how do I calculate their age in years?  </p>\n""",1,How do I calculate someone's age in C#?,"c#,.net,datetime,",64,376

11,1,1248,2008-07-31,23:55:37,1286,130055,"b'<p>Given a specific <code>DateTime</code> value, how do I display relative time, like:</p>\n\n<ul>\n<li>2 hours ago</li>\n<li>3 days ago</li>\n<li>a month ago</li>\n</ul>\n'",1,Calculate relative time in C#,"c#,datetime,time,datediff,relative-time-span,",34,528
```

plus if you rename the file from 'Posts.csv' to 'posts.csv' your code should work.

Comment: Is there a reason why the other xml does work for example tags.xml. I dont include a heading on both files but post does not work. I try it out.

Comment: Is there a way to add the header because the file is actually to large.

Comment: Yes, you need add fieldnames attribute in the csv.DictReader constructor as follows: `dr = csv.DictReader(fin, fieldnames=keys_of_csv) ` where keys_of_csv is list of fieldnames

Comment: Regarding your question on the xml - csv module cannot read such format, so it is not the case.